# CKEditor Memory Leak on setData()

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks, ckeditor

I think I'm having some big memory leaks related to the CKeditor setData() function. I have a web app where users can design their own content with Javascript. CKEditor is used as the WYSIWYG editor for the users to write content of each part of the design.

Each time a user click on a editable text-element in their design, editor.setData is called, and it sets the CKEditor data to whatever is within the text element of the users design that is being clicked.

This works fine for a few times, but each time a user click a new text element, and .setData() is called, the app gets slower, slower and slower, until the website crashes. I've tried disabling setData() function in my Javascript and I have no memory leaks or performance issues when I do so.

Anyone had similar issues? Anyone have any advice of how I can avoid this memory leak and performance loss?

The function that is being called, and that create the performance loss is:

```
function clickTextElement() {
    var location = $(this);
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    location.addClass('selected');
    $('#main-tools').hide();

    if(location.hasClass('textarea')){
        $('#imageeditor').hide();
        $('#texteditor').show();
        editor.setData( $('.selected').html() );
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds very impropable that it's ckeditor. I've used ckeditor for quite a long time and I do tens, sometimes a hundred `setData()` calls throught an editors lifetime. Check what is taking up memory by taking a heap snapshot / recording heap allocations (chrome developer tools). The tools to profile vary from browser to browser so try a few even and try to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Could you show us what version, what kind of config and what kind of input you use for cke? Do you use any custom plugins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to improve the performance of this function by first adding the following code:

```
editor.document.clearCustomData();
editor.document.removeAllListeners();
editor.window.getFrame().clearCustomData();
editor.window.getFrame().removeAllListeners();
```

At the beginning of the function clickTextElement(); the idea is to clear all data related to the editor before it loads new data into it. I'm unsure exactly which of these calls that improves the performance the most, I tried uncommenting one by one to see the performance loss/improvement and it was difficult to differ them.

I also removed a lot of fonts from CKEditor Config. Previously I was loading a lot of Google Fonts into CKEditor, I would say maybe 50+. Now I reduced this to about 15.

Together both of these additions improved the performance a lot. Before I could click (call clickTextElement() ) about 10-20 times before the memory ran out. I have now tried clicking/calling the function hundreds of times without any noticable performance loss.

If someone would like to add information regarding this fix and regarding the clearCustomData() and removeAllListeners() function calls, please do.

Comment: Could you report a ticket on http://dev.ckeditor.com for this issue? We would definitely need a sample which shows the issue, because there must be some additional requirements to reproduce this problem. As Nanotlep wrote - in normal situation CKEditor does not cause such leaks - e.g. all those methods clearing data and listeners are called, so it's strange that you had to call them yourself.