# CkEditor setData function gets slower and slower after multiple uses?

Tags: javascript, performance, ckeditor4.x

I am using CkEditor to load/Edit Notes section of different Tasks. Previously I used HTMLbox editor now I switched to CkEditor. But now there is big problem comes after migrates, CkEditor setData function gets slower and slower after multiple uses?

Here I am calling setContent function multiple time. in beginning its runs faster but after some time its execution time increase exponentially.

```
var NoteBox = {
  ckEditor:{},
  initialise: function() {
    this.ckEditor = CKEDITOR.replace("taskNote-area");
  },
  setContent: function(notes) {
    var _funcName = 'setContent';
    log.timerOn(_funcName);
    NoteBox.ckEditor.setData(notes, {
        callback: function() {
            NoteBox.ckEditor.resetDirty();
            NoteBox.ckEditor.resetUndo();
            NoteBox.ckEditor.focus();
            log.timer(_funcName,_funcName);
        }
    } );
},
```

Here is Console log. execution of SetData function.

```
setContent(setContent: 0.129)
setContent(setContent: 3.352)
setContent(setContent: 3.521)
setContent(setContent: 73.587)
setContent(setContent: 87.653)
setContent(setContent: 899.093)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388256/ckeditor-memory-leak-on-setdata 
I have seen this question and this is not helping me.. FYI

Comment: Good question, in all kind of project, performance is the most important feature.